# self made methods in subclass showing syntax error

Tags: java, parsing, methods, void

I''m having some problems creating the methods parameter and getArea, it just returning a syntax error and i don't know why, and the last bracket says that it went to end of file while parsing just take a look through the code, and i've added comments to show what works and what doesn't work, if there is a comment that doesn't have any issues written in it then that part of the code is fine, if it does have an issue please take a look at it and help me out, I'm a novice java programmer and a novice programmer in general so forgive my trespasses -XATjeffreyericgutierrezMK64

```
/*
 * XATJeffreyEricGutierrezMK64
 */
package rectangle;

//create subclass rectangle, and declare to variables side1 and side2
class Rectangle2 {
double side1;
double side2;

//create Rectangle constructor

Rectangle2 () {

  side1 = 8;
  side2 = 12;

}

//create height and width variables

Rectangle2 (double height, double width) {

side1 = height;
side2 = width;

//return the area of this rectangle(doesn't work)

Object.getArea(){    
return side1 * side2;  

}

//Return the parameter of this rectangle(doesn't work either)

double getParameter(){   

getParameter = side1 + side2 * 2;

return;

}

//set a new side for this rectangle(doesn't work though

void setSide(double height, double width) 

side1 = height;
side2 = width; 

}

} //says i reached the end of the file without parsing
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because your code is wrong in many places, you don't use bracket correctly, use misuse concepts. Compere your code to this:

```
class Rectangle2 {
    double side1;
    double side2;

    public Rectangle2() {
        side1 = 8;
        side2 = 12;
    }

    public Rectangle2(double height, double width) {
        side1 = height;
        side2 = width;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return side1 * side2;
    }

    double getParameter() {
        return side1 + side2 * 2;
    }

    public void setSide(double height, double width) {
        side1 = height;
        side2 = width;
    }

}
```

and try to analyze your mistakes

Comment: @BoristheSpider sorry, I also still learning. Thanks for your remark

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thanks again, I will treat your comments seriously